# Unable to File Upload From Angular 8 to Asp.net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, angular8

I have asp.net core server (using .net core 2.2) that has [FileUploadController](https://github.com/phonemyatt/TestPlaygroundServer/blob/master/Controllers/FileUploadController.cs) which listens to post request for incoming file.

```
[HttpPost("Upload")]
// public async Task<IActionResult> Upload([FromForm(Name="file")]IFormFile file) {
// public async Task<IActionResult> Upload([FromForm]IFormFile file) {
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file) {
   Console.WriteLine("***" + file);
   if(file == null) return BadRequest("NULL FILE");
   if(file.Length == 0) return BadRequest("Empty File");
       Console.WriteLine("***" + host.WebRootPath);
   if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(host.WebRootPath))
   {
      host.WebRootPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot");
   }
   var uploadsFolderPath = Path.Combine(host.WebRootPath, "uploads");
   if (!Directory.Exists(uploadsFolderPath)) Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadsFolderPath);
       var fileName = "Master" + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
       var filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolderPath, fileName);
       using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
       {
          await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
       }
       return Ok("Okay");
}
```

I have created angular app (using angular version 8) which can choose file to upload at [ClientApplication](https://github.com/phonemyatt/TestPlayground) and I have created three post service that called to the api "http://localhost:5000/api/fileupload/upload".

1. Standard Angular HttpClient Post. when server reads, the IFormFile is null.

   ```
   const formData: FormData = new FormData();
   formData.append('file', file, file.name);
   // return this.http.post(this.endpoint, file);
   return this.http.post(this.endpoint, formData); // Problem solved
   ```

[image: 400 Bad Request NULL FILE]

2. Added HttpHeaders, I try empty headers, undefined and other propose solution from stackoverflow and google.

   ```
   const header = new HttpHeaders() //1
   header.append('enctype', 'multipart/form-data'); //2
   header.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data'); //3
   ```

If I put httpheader with resources in request, server gives 415 (unsupported media type)

[image: 415 Bad Request Unsupported Media Type]

3. I try HttpRequest from '@angular/common/http' which finally give me result that i want.

   ```
   const formData: FormData = new FormData();
   formData.append('file', file, file.name);
   const req = new HttpRequest('POST', this.endpoint, formData);
   return this.http.request(req);
   ```

I want to know is it a bug or my misunderstanding? If you check online tutorial, most of the developers use "this.HttpClient.post". 
From what I read, I can use httpclient.post and angular framework will auto set the proper header for user. It seems like it's not doing the job.

> After thorough investigation, first error is my mistake of using file
>   instead of formData, second error is header "content-type" declare in
>   httpinterceptor which after removed, it load the file as expected.

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // add authorization header with jwt token if available
        // if (request.url.indexOf('/upload')) {
        //     return next.handle(request);
        // }
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        if (currentUser && token) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                //    'Content-Type': 'application/json' <---- Main Problem.
                }
            });
        }
        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => this.handleError(err)));
    }
}
```

Server: "https://github.com/phonemyatt/TestPlaygroundServer"

Client: "https://github.com/phonemyatt/TestPlayground"

Comment: Try this: `public async Task<IActionResult> Upload([FromForm] IFormFile file) {}`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I have tried with FromForm Attribute, I still can't upload it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example that doesn't work, you are passing `file` into `post(...)` instead of `formData`. It should be:

```
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file, file.name);
return this.http.post(this.endpoint, formData);
```

The code you show for the controller appears to be correct, so this should be the only change that's required. You do *not* need to set any custom headers on the request that is sent from Angular.

Answer (score 2):

Below code work for you

```
  uploadSecond(file: File) {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);
    return this.http.post('https://localhost:44393/api/fileupload/UploadSecond', formData);
  }
```

Then in your controller

```
[HttpPost("UploadSecond")]
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadSecond([FromForm]IFormFile file)
```

Comment: After changing into this, I got this error. System.IO.InvalidDataException: Missing content-type boundary

Comment: Try to remove the httpOptions like this `return this.http.post(url, formData);` to see if it work or not

Comment: It can reach to my upload api but the file always null.

Comment: file received always null. is it angular bug?

Comment: Did you already try with [FromForm]IFormFile file and IFormFile file ?

Comment: yes, i try with [FromFile(Name="file")], [FromFile] and without [FromFile].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195317/discussion-between-tony-ngo-and-phonemyatt).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FormData in client you can get files like this.

```
[HttpPost("Upload"), DisableRequestSizeLimit]
        public ActionResult Upload()
        {
            try
            {
                var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
                var folderName = Path.Combine("Resources","Images");
                var pathToSave = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), folderName);

                if (file.Length > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                    var fullPath = Path.Combine(pathToSave, fileName);
                    var dbPath = Path.Combine(folderName, fileName);

                    using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        file.CopyTo(stream);
                    }

                    return Ok(new { dbPath });
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
            }
        }
```